# For loop populates whole instead of one instance

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm creating a booking system in Java to prevent double bookings i have created a for loop that should change a Boolean to booked once the booking is made however it is changing all the bookings to booked when i only want one instance of booking so no one else can make a booking.

```
public static boolean booked;

private void FSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

for ( int i = 0; i < Airplane.Fseat.length; i++)
{
    String seat = FCol.getSelectedItem().toString() + FRow.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String items = Snack.getSelectedItem().toString() + "  " + Drink.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Airplane.Fseat[i] = seat;
    Airplane.item[i] = items;

    if (Airplane.Fseat[i] != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Seat number is First class " + Airplane.Fseat[i].toString() + "\n" +"Food and drink " + " " + Airplane.item[i].toString());
        i++;
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot book already taken");
    }
}
```

Comment: You set `Airplane.Fseat[i] = seat;` before you test if it is null. So naturally you will never reach "Cannot book already taken"

Comment: What would you recommend changing it to?

Comment: I couldnt say, i'm not sure what FCol, FRow, Snack or Drink are. Also you mention that you change a boolean to true once something is booked however I see no booleans in your code. Its hard to make suggestions when I dont know how to construct the code to match your program

Comment: sorry ive updated the code to show the Boolean and Fcol, Frow Snack Drink are fields that are stored inside arrays

Answer (score 0):

You have not put any condition to check, how a particular seat will be set selected.

So you will need to modify your code as:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < Airplane.Fseat.length; i++)
        {

            String seat = FCol.getSelectedItem().toString() + FRow.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String items = Snack.getSelectedItem().toString() + "  " + Drink.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(your_condition_to_check_if_this_seat_is_selcted ){       

          Airplane.Fseat[i] = seat;
          Airplane.item[i] = items;

         }

            if (Airplane.Fseat[i] != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Seat number is First class " + Airplane.Fseat[i].toString() + "\n" +"Food and drink " + " " + Airplane.item[i].toString());
                i++;
            }

            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot book already taken");
            }
        }
```